# Generate Rss from wordpress database

Tags: php, rss

I have blog on wordpress and site, what using wordpress RSS on one machine.
My idea is connect to database of wordpress and generate Rss for my site in code of my site.

Any ideas how doing it?

In code of wordpress i found

```
header('Content-Type: ' . feed_content_type('rss-http') . '; charset=' . get_option('blog_charset'), true);
$more = 1;

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>'; ?>
<rss version="0.92">
<channel>
    <title><?php bloginfo_rss('name'); wp_title_rss(); ?></title>
    <link><?php bloginfo_rss('url') ?></link>
    <description><?php bloginfo_rss('description') ?></description>
    <lastBuildDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_lastpostmodified('GMT'), false); ?></lastBuildDate>
    <docs>http://backend.userland.com/rss092</docs>
    <language><?php echo get_option('rss_language'); ?></language>
    <?php do_action('rss_head'); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <item>
        <title><?php the_title_rss(); ?></title>
                <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>]]></description>
        <link><?php the_permalink_rss() ?></link>
        <?php do_action('rss_item'); ?>
    </item>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

But i can't just copy that code in code of my site. Where i can find bloginfo_rss method code?

In database i can find fields like content, title, but i can't find description fields and sort logick for that posts.

```
 $this->_blogAdapter = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'password',
    'dbname' => 'database'
 ));
```

I can connect to my blog, but i don't know how i can take that all fields, logick of sort and another. Any resolve for it?

Comment: $posts = $this->_blogAdapter->select()
                    ->from(array ('p'=>'blog_posts'))
                    ->where ('post_status = ?','publish')
                    ->where ('post_type = ?','post')
                    ->limit ($limit)
                    ->query()
                    ->fetchAll();
           return $posts;
I can get all posts now, but i have uncoding problem with utf-8 and russian words

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
$blog = new Model_Blog();
$post = '?lang=' . $lang;
$this->view->entries = $blog->getItems($lang);
```

In model:

```
protected function _createAdapter ()
{
     $this->_blogAdapter = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
        'host'     => 'xxx',
        'username' => 'xxx',
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'dbname'   => 'xxx'
     ));
     $this->_blogAdapter->query('SET NAMES UTF8');
}
protected function _getPosts ($limit = 0)
{
   $posts = $this->_blogAdapter->select()
            ->from(array ('p'=>'xxx_posts'))
            ->where ('post_status = ?','publish')
            ->where ('post_type = ?','post')
            ->order ('post_date DESC')
            ->limit ($limit)
            ->query()
            ->fetchAll();
   return $posts;
}
public function getItems ($lang ='ru', $need = 3)
{
    $posts=$this->_getPosts();
    $items=array();
    foreach ($posts as $key=>$post) {
        $items [$key] ['link'] = $post ['guid'].'&lang='.$lang;
        $items [$key] ['description'] = $this->_getText($post ['post_content'], $lang);
        $items [$key] ['title'] = $this->_getTitle($post ['post_title'], $lang);
    }
    $validItems = array_filter($items,array("self", "_valid"));
    if (count($validItems) > $need) {
        return array_slice($validItems, 0, $need);
    } else {
        return $validItems;
    }
}
```